# How do I share my Thunderbolt Ethernet through WiFi in a hidden way?

Tags: security, internet-sharing

I want to share my internet connection in such a way that my SSID is not visible/discoverable on other devices. I want to allow access only to devices which know my SSID/mac address. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: could you please elaborate, what platform and router you are using?

Comment: @DaanvanHoek The OP is talking about the Mac's built in internet sharing option. In other words, their Mac has an internet connection via Ethernet (through a Thunderbolt > Ethernet adapter) and they are configuring their sharing preferences to share that connection via WiFi to other users. In this case their Mac is the router.

Comment: @DaanvanHoek I'm not using a router - I have an ethernet connection, and I want to share it over Wifi in a hidden manner as mentioned.

Comment: If you hide it, you make it more attractive to anyone looking. Your phone/computer is constantly yelling, 'Hey hidden SSID, where are you?" all the time it's not connected - see this from security SE - http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38365/how-risky-is-connecting-to-a-hidden-wireless-network/38367#38367

Answer (score 1):

While most routers provide the option to hide your SSID by not broadcasting it, to the best of my knowledge there is no built-in macOS way to do the same thing.

However, if the main reason you wanted to hide it was because you wanted to limit access to only those devices you wanted to connect to it, you can do this by setting a password on the Wi-Fi network your Mac is creating/sharing.

**You can do this from the System Preferences > Sharing pane.**

When you look at the Internet Sharing options, click on "Wi-Fi Options" button at the bottom-right of the screen and then you will be able to set the name, channel, and password of your ad-hoc network.

By doing this, other devices may be able to *see* your network, but they can't connect without the password.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I've already done that. Maybe there's a terminal way to do it?